# How to find out, how the app communicates over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an Android app (hansa app) for my water tap. I can use the app to open and close the water tap via Bluetooth.
I would like to build my own script in python, which sends the open and close command to the water tap via Bluetooth.
My problem is that I can't currently find out what exactly the app sends.

I have already created an hci trace on an Android cell phone and viewed it in Wireshark. But I only ever see exactly the same opcodes and values there. But there should actually be two different ones (open and close)
I have also decompiled the app, but I can find even less out there.
Does anyone have any idea how I can find the right commands in Wireshark?

[Wireshark Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7j2W.png)

Comment: You may get some ideas reading through: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=bluetooth

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer for a specification?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Hansa provide their app API publicly, so as Morrison Chang and Risto suggested, your next bets are to either contact the manufacturer or reverse engineer this yourself. If contacting Hansa doesn't yield anything, I would personally use a third party app (e.g. nRF Connect) and try and send the opcode that you saw in the Wireshark trace. If it is in fact the only data that is being sent over Bluetooth and it is always exactly the same, maybe this is some form of toggle command that the firmware on the water tap understands to turn the tap ON if it is OFF and turn the tap OFF if it is ON.